# Skip X-rows in bulk SQL import command line without erase previous data

Tags: mysql, macos, command-line, import

I tried import very large file using cmd line, via command:

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword --default-character-set=utf8 mydb < /Users/user1/Downloads/dump.sql
```

But after some time i obtained a message:

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 8498: MySQL server has gone away
```

So, i need to start import again from line 8498 without erase previously inserted data.

How can i do that?

Many thanks..

Comment: How was the dump generated? That error makes me wonder if there is something wrong with your file. Usually cmd-line imports won't timeout. If the dump was created my 'mysqldump' there may be a 'drop table' at the start (depending on params for the dump). Doing the import this way doesn't give you much freedom to skip records without editing the 'dump.sql' file.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with ethrbunny questions and comments, to answer your  explicit question, read on ...

I don't have any way to test this, but something like

```
tail -n +8497 /Users/user1/Downloads/dump.sql | mysql -uroot -ppassword --default-character-set=utf8 mydb
```

As the man page for linux tail says

```
-n, --lines=K
output the last K lines, instead of the last 10; 
or use -n +K to output lines starting with the Kth
```

(I've seen some versions of tail that will don't need -n, just +K so some experimentation on your part may be required.)

or the same idea with `sed`, i.e.

```
sed -n '9498,9999999p' /Users/user1/Downloads/dump.sql | mysql -uroot -ppassword --default-character-set=utf8 mydb
```

The 999999 is meant to be a number greater than the number of records in your file.

IHTH.

Comment: If the dump was made with mysqldump then line xxx might be part of a bulk insert statement and not be valid mysql (by itself) - IE 'insert into table( cola,colb..) values ... (many lines later ) .. more data'

Comment: @ethrbunny : agreed. I don't know the format of mysql dump files. If it just a bunch of records though the above may work. If my answer doesn't help the O.P., I'll take it down. Good luck to all.

Comment: The OP didn't give any history. I think your approach is valid for some types of dumps.

Answer (score 0):

Following from @shellter - one avenue would be to import the data into a temp table, then do a 'insert into <final table> select * from <temp table> limit <start line, lines to import>.

I suspect that something is wrong with your dump though.